# How to find Windows Azure SQL Server domain

Tags: sql-server, azure, sharepoint-2013

I am attempting to install Sharepoint on a VM I had Azure create. I also created a SQL server to hos the Sharepoint config database, however, as I am setting up Sharepoint, the wizard is asking me for domain/password to my SQL Server.

My server address is something like: testestest3333.database.windows.net

Suppose the username is 'admin' and pw is 'password'

Under this scenario, which would be the domain to add on my domain/username login?

Sorry, I am very new to Sharepoint and SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use SQL Azure for Sharepoint databases, you have to install a VM with SQL Server on it and use that.